# Access api content using React CORS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, curl

I'm studying react and I'm developing a little web app using the RIOT Api (League of legends api), and I can't access using fetch or axios and others.. because no access through browser (CORS).

The way I can access to this API is using the action curl, so there is any way to make a curl action using react, or which way is the best to make it?

Thanks.

Comment: This really doesn't have to do anything with React.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to fetch data from the frontend? You should be able to make a request from your backend application without CORS issues. Your browser won't allow it from the frontend though.

There are fixes but most involve using a proxy:
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Yes, the problem is that I have a search form, so when click on the submit button it execute a function which has the fetch function. That's creating the issue.

Comment: @carlesgrau aside from using public proxy services which are unreliable, you can write some server code that makes the request, and then your client makes a request to *your* server.

Comment: As @FakeRainBrigand said, server request is the safest and best way to go. Fairly easy to set up aswell.